# How to modify a parallel element

Tags: css, shopify

I have a span that has the attribute `doubly-currency="USD"`. I need to `display:none` in that element, but also in its "brother" element.

The HTML structure is the following:

```
<span data-money="" class="product-installments">
     <span clas="money">5x de</span>
     <span class="money" doubly-currency-brl="13400" doubly-currency-usd="3460.8331822" doubly-currency="USD">$34.61</span>
</span>
```

How can I make the other element, that has also the class "money", be hidden when the `doubly-currency` is equal to USD?

** I cannot use javascript to solve that.

Comment: This is not possible with just CSS, you'll need to use JS (unless you can modify your structure) Edit: As you've edited in that you can't use JS, is changing the structure a possibility?

Comment: Got it... I think that I have to do something different then. Edit: I'll have to search more to see if I can do that through structure. Thank you!

Comment: if you could reverse the order of your siblings in the markup then you could show them in right order with flexbox position and row-reverse direction. Doing so you could easily hide the element and its following sibling

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Are you able to modify the HTML, so that the element with `doubly-currency` comes before the other span? If yes, you can invert it and then do `span[doubly-currency=USD] + span { display: none; }`. If you cannot invert them, then it's not possible without JS

Comment: Great! I did that and it worked perfectly. Thank you for the help!